# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. API Codewars

Tags: javascript

Eu estava fazendo uma requisição na API do Codewars e tive este problema. Porém, não sei como solucioná-la.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/ThaysMrtns?access_key=DuNKdgzmE585M2e9CPJj' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
class UsuarioController{
    constructor(){

    }
    //Requisição de dados da API para o nosso usuário
    dadosUsuario(){
        let requisicao = new XMLHttpRequest();
        requisicao.open("GET", `https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/ThaysMrtns?access_key=DuNKdgzmE585M2e9CPJj`);
        requisicao.send();
        //let dados = requisicao.JSON.parse(requisicao.responseText);
        console.log(requisicao.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está tendo problemas com o CORS, saiba mais sobre: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#:~:text=Cross%2Dorigin%20resource%20sharing%20(CORS,scripts%2C%20iframes%2C%20and%20videos.

Comment: Sim, muito obrigado!